# Customizations of CKEditor are not applied in Connections 5 CR6

Tags: ckeditor, ibm-connections, hcl

Following the [documentation of JS customizations in connections](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSYGQH_6.0.0/admin/customize/t_customize_override_js.html), I want to customize the CKEditor. I unziped the web ressources jar from blogs in `{provision_dir}/webresources/`:

```
unzip -d web-ressources-extracted com.ibm.lconn.blogs.web.resources_*.jar
```

Now there is a file called `ckeditor.js` in `web-ressources-extracted/resources`. According to [this presentation](https://engage.ug/Engage.nsf/pages/2014_Slides_a/$file/Engage2014_IBMConnections_CustomizeIt.pdf), I  copied it to `{customization_dir}/lconn/blogs` and edited `{customization_dir}/lconn/blogs/ckeditor.js`.

For testing purpose, I removed the `Undo` button in the toolbar:

```
{
    name: 'tools',
    items: [/*'Undo',*/ 'Redo', 'MenuPaste', 'Find', 'LotusSpellChecker', 'ShowBlocks', 'IbmPermanentPen']
}
```

After restarting the common-application, I checked the dedicated blogs application as well as the blogs module in communitys. Both still have the `Undo` button as first element in the toolbar. It also doesn't help to checkout `LotusConnections-config.yml` and update `versionStamp`, which should update all caching buster timestamps on javascript files.

The editor is activated in `{customization_dir}/tiny/editors/connections/config.js` by setting `editor: "CKEditor"`.

Why are my changes not applied in the CKEditor of blogs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized that there was a mistake in the target folder: I copied the editor config file to `{customization_dir}/lconn/blogs/ckeditor.js` instead of `{customization_dir}/javascript/lconn/blogs/ckeditor.js`.

After fixing the path and restarting common, it works.